# How to "reverse" 〜てから〜てはなりません?

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

Consider the sentence:

> シャワーを浴び**てから**、プールに入らなく**てはなりません**。

As far as I understand, てから here is used to glue them into “You must go to the pool after taking a shower” which makes the most sense.

However, I was confused at first and thought it meant “After taking a shower, you must go to the pool [and nowhere else]”, which doesn't make a lot of sense in real life.

What would be the grammatical way to “reverse” the sentence? Would it be something like this?

> After you finish your work, you must go home [and do nothing else which is not going home].
>
> 仕事が終わりしまったら、家に帰らなくてはなりません。

> You must report to me after finishing your work.
>
> 仕事を終わってから、私に報告しなくてはなりません。

Answer (score 2):

They are to some extent ambiguous, just as (I think) *You must go to the pool after taking a shower* is. I don't think there's any grammatical reason that it can't mean *After taking a shower, you must go to the pool [and nowhere else]*. As you say, it is unlikely, but it is a matter of meaning.

Practically, you also got the answer already. Basically:

- A(し)てから、B(し)なくてはならない : You need to do A first before doing B.

It is like (AしてからBする) + なくてはならない = *It must be 'do A, then do B'*.

The 'reverse' version is just use たら=if

- A(し)たらB(し)なくてはならない = If you do A, you must do B.

So, with the correct conjugation,

- 仕事が終わったら、家に帰らなくてはなりません。

This means, as you intend, *After finishing the work, you must go home (you can't stay in the office)*.

---

These things said, one example I came up with is:

- 仕事が終わってから、子供を迎えに行かなくてはなりません

This can be 仕事が終わったら, but I think both are fine and usually both are interpreted as *After work, I must go pick up my kid*. Ultimately it depends on the meaning.

Comment: Haven't read, but found https://nihongobu.net/te-tekara-tara/

Comment: Is it ungrammatical or not idiomatic to use しまったら to emphasize the completeness of the action?

Comment: To my native English ear "You must go to the pool after taking a shower" is just weird. It is definitely saying that after I have taken a shower I have no choice but to go to the pool. A natural sentence would be "You must take a shower before going to the pool". I'm rather surprised to learn that シャワーを浴びてから、プールに入らなくてはなりません does sound natural.

Comment: @homocomputeris 1. しまう needs て-form, so it would be 仕事が終わってしまったら. 2. Using 終わってしまう here does not sound completely right to me; Perhaps it's better to use the transitive 終えてしまったら  - 仕事を終えてしまったら家に帰らなくてはならない. （終わってしまう may sound odd because it sounds like feeling sorry for finishing the work)